# MS Access - Subform Combo Box Filtered via Main Form

Tags: ms-access

Good Morning,

I have an issue that just sort of popped up and it is stumping me to no end. I have an MS Access database we built to handle our small service department for golf carts. We have a form for service requests (fServiceRequest) that we input the customer (Customer) information (selected from a combo box based on another table), as well as the service information and also a subform (fServiceRequest_sfCarServiced) to select the golf carts to be worked on.

The subform has a combo box (SerialNumber) to select the cars serial number. In lieu of having the combo box list all 4k golf carts we have in the system it is filtered based on the customer. To do this I have a text box on the main form (txtCustNumber) that gets the customer number from the combo box on the main form. Until recently this has been working with absolutely no issue.

Yesterday I updated the subform, an update that has nothing to do with the filter, and now I get an error the first time I open the form after a fresh open of the database to input the parameter value that is set by the txtCustNumber. If I make a small change to the subform that requires me to save the subform due to a change and reopen it then my problem goes away and everything is back to "normal".

As soon as I close the DB and reopen it I have the same issue again.

Comment: Apparently the change must have something to do with the filter or there wouldn't be an error now. Really can't help without viewing code. Might post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.

Comment: The change had to do with the subform and what records overall to display based on a checkbox. The filter is via the SQL query.

In a brief moment of "hey lets try something" I moved the txtCustNumber field to the sub form and I believe this has resolved my issue. Why it was all of a sudden an issue is a mystery still but this appears to be working again.